# MigraDoc - Table Border but no Cell/Row/Column Borders

Tags: c#, migradoc

I am struggling to implement what seems should be something straight forward, but having not much luck. I need a MigraDoc table to render with just the Table border, excluding all cells in between:

[image]

I have followed the remarks on this post:

[How do you add a border around a table in MigraDoc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45737856/how-do-you-add-a-border-around-a-table-in-migradoc)

Useful information but I havent been able to implement a full fix from it?
I have the following code run just before the table is added to the section:

```
        table.Borders.Visible = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count - 2; i++)
        {
            table.Rows[i].Borders.Bottom.Visible = false;
        }
```

Which at first seemed like it did the job... until I come across a table that follows onto the next page... The bottom row border is obviously only rendered for the very bottom row and does not account for PageBreaks mid-table.

Surely there must be a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

*EDIT: I appreciate this is somewhat of an old question, but just incase anyone ends up here looking for an answer...*

Try using the `SetEdge` option. There's two ways you could do it, depending on whether you know how many table rows or columns you're going to have (static content), or you don't know yet (dynamic content).

**Option 1: Static table content**

Set your table up first, so all the columns, cells and rows exist, then add an edge border to your table with

```
table.SetEdge(a, b, x, y, Edge.Box, BorderStyle.Single, 1, Colors.Black);
```

The first four numbers `a, b, x, y` indicate which of the table cells you want to add a borders to, the first two numbers are the top left column then row (in your case to border the whole table, this should be `0, 0`) and the second two numbers are the bottom right corner column then row (as per your example this is `3, 4`, assuming the heading is a heading row).

After `Edge.Box`, the options are `border style, border width, border color`.

You can then add any extra individual borders per cell or row after as normal, so to add a border at the bottom of your header row as per your example...

```
headerRow.Borders.Bottom.Width = 0.2;
headerRow.Borders.Bottom.Color = Colors.Black;
```

**Option 2: Dynamic table content**

If you don't know how many rows or columns are in your table becuase the content is dynamic, the first four numbers in SetEdge could be set with `this.table.Columns.Count`and `this.table.Rows.Count` - for example :

```
table.SetEdge(0, 0, this.table.Columns.Count, this.table.Rows.Count, Edge.Box, BorderStyle.Single, 1, Colors.Black);
```

**References**

For more info, see this post:
https://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=3598

And it's also here in the MigraDoc Example (search for SetEdge):
http://pdfsharp.net/wiki/HelloMigraDoc-sample.ashx